# Java Servlet error - JasperReport (ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.ReferenceMap)

Tags: java, exception, servlets, jasper-reports, apache-commons-collection

The Java/Servlets/JasperReports based application was working fine before, but now not showing the PDF report and throws `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

I use the libraries:

- commons-collections-3.2.1.jar
- commons-digester-1.7.jar
- commons-logging-1.1.3.jar
- iText-2.1.7.js2.jar
- jasperreports-5.2.0.jar
- log4j-1.2.16.jar
- postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar

### Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.collections.ReferenceMap
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.DefaultExtensionsRegistry.<init>(DefaultExtensionsRegistry.java:97)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.ClassUtils.instantiateClass(ClassUtils.java:59)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment.createDefaultRegistry(ExtensionsEnvironment.java:81)
at net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment.<clinit>(ExtensionsEnvironment.java:69)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser.<clinit>(JRStyledTextParser.java:83)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.<init>(JRBaseFiller.java:123)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:88)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:103)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.<init>(JRVerticalFiller.java:61)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createFiller(JRFiller.java:179)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:108)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:569)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:447)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperRunManager.runReportToPdf(JasperRunManager.java:862)
at Reportes.ReporteRecomendacionServlet.generarReporte(ReporteRecomendacionServlet.java:95)
at Reportes.ReporteRecomendacionServlet.processRequest(ReporteRecomendacionServlet.java:54)
at Reportes.ReporteRecomendacionServlet.doGet(ReporteRecomendacionServlet.java:127)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Comment: Post your java and jrxml code.

Answer (score 1):

With commons-collections.jar should be enough, check that you have the jar on WEB-INF/lib of your web application